# How to use email to message someone on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I want to use my email (in apple mail app) to send a message to a friend on Facebook. Is there an email I can send it to from my mail app? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, as of now it's not possible. You cannot send message on Facebook via email. This feature is not available now.